# Get all values that are the same across records in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to get a list of all values that are the same across all records using SQL.

```
SELECT
    Record,
    Value
FROM Record r
INNER JOIN Value v
    ON v.RecordId = r.RecordId

Record | Value
1      | a
1      | b
1      | c
2      | a
2      | b
3      | a
3      | b
3      | c
3      | d
```

I need the results to be:

```
Value
a
b
```

Comment: If you had one more row `2 e`, the result would remain the same: `a b`, right?

Comment: That is correct.  Only values across all records.  If `2 c` were added, then `a b c` would be the result.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `JOIN` for your query.  I think this is equivalent:

```
SELECT v.RecordId, v.Value
FROM Value v;
```

From here, you want to find values that are in all records:

```
select v.value
from value v
group by v.value
having count(recordid) = (select count(distinct recordid) from value);
```

This finds values that have all records *with values*.  If you want all records, then:

```
select v.value
from value v
group by v.value
having count(recordid) = (select count(*) from record r);
```

Comment: He still may need a join with `Record`. Table `Record` could hold a subset of `RecordId`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . Although it is possible, I would be surprised if a table called `value` had a column called `RecordId` that had values that were not in `Record.RecordId`.

Comment: The columns and tables are not important.  This logic works.  I can now apply it.  Thank You.